# Como o compilador sabe a diferença do tipo que estou usando no downcasting?

Tags: java, herança, cast, polimorfismo

As classes `Felino` e `Ave` herdam de `Criatura`, os valores são hipotéticos apenas para informar a diferença entre atributos especializados.

```java
Criatura c1 = new Felino("Preto", true);
Criatura c2 = new Ave("Azul", 1);
```

Nesta situação não acontece qualquer erro de atribuição.

Quando se realiza o *cast*

```java
Felino f1 = (Felino) c1; // Cast Ok
Felino f2 = (Felino) c2; // Exception
```

Como os objetos `c1` e `c2` são do tipo `Criatura` e não possui os atributos e campos especializados das classes derivadas correto? Como o compilador faz a distinção e lança a exceção em tempo de execução?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiro vamos começar usar a nomenclatura correta das coisas, [o que você chama de atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), então está repetindo a mesma coisa na afirmação, melhorando sua pergunta e pontuando:

> Como os objetos `c1` e `c2` são do tipo `Criatura` e não possui os métodos e campos especializados das classes derivadas, correto?

Não, estes objetos possuem a estrutura dos tipos que foram usados para criá-los, no caso o tipo `Felino` e `Ave` respectivamente. Portanto, sabendo disto, imagino que já começa ficar mais fácil entender como o compilador sabe.

Quando você declara qual o tipo da variável significa apenas que todo o tratamento considerará que o objeto é deste tipo, mas isto é abstrato, o objeto concreto é do tipo mais especializado, o que está na memória é o objeto que foi criado.

A variável sendo do tipo mais geral o código só poderá acessar os membros que estão disponíveis nele, mesmo que o objeto concreto tenha outros membros do tipo estendido nada poderá ser acessado, é uma proibição artificial de proteção, não é uma limitação técnica.

O primeiro *cast* está apenas dizendo que o objeto deve ser considerado algo como um `Felino`, portanto neste momento está dando o direito de acesso a todos os membros deste tipo e por isso pode guardar em uma variável do tipo `Felino`. Os membros de `Criatura` continuarão acessível porque todo tipo `Felino` tem acesso a estes membros. Note que isto não tem custo de processamento.

No segundo está tentando fazer a mesma coisa, mas está dando acesso aos membros de `Felino` a um objeto que concretamente é um `Ave`, portanto não tem esses membros pretendidos, então dá erro.

O compilador sabe que `c2` tem um tipo na [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) (leia a definição) - `Criatura` - e um tipo no seu valor - `Ave`, por isso o **valor** tem seu tipo conhecido.

O erro comum que muita gente comete é entender que a variável é o valor, variável é apenas o local de armazenamento com um nome, e em linguagens de tipagem estática ela tem um tipo. O valor tem tipo em todas as linguagens de programação (grosso modo, sempre tem alguma diferente, a maioria dos Assembly's seria exemplo). Separe esses dois conceitos de sua mente e fica fácil entender porque o compilator saber o tipo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado, um amigo me explicou e junto de sua explicação ficou bem claro.